# opposite of object destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the following example. Is there a shorthand for the field asignment

```
let myObj = {someField: 'someValue'}
let foo = 'value'

myObj.foo = foo // I would like to do the opposite of object destructuring: const {foo} = myObj. I don't want to repeat foo twice.
```

Comment: You mean `const myObj = { foo: "value" }`?

Comment: I don't think there is, unless you do `const foo = 'value'; const myObj = { foo };`, but since you are using constants it needs to be your last declaration.

Comment: myObj = {..myObj, foo}

Comment: @Lev Thats a cool trick, but it wont work on a constant.

Comment: but then I repeat myObj

Comment: If you already have things called `myObj` and `foo`, you can't avoid referencing them again in order to say "I want to associated `myObj` with `foo`".

Comment: @somethinghere, updated post

Comment: @Lev Note that the `{...myObj, foo}` syntax [is not a standard, yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread).

Answer (score 9):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with a [short hand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```js
const myObj = {}
const foo = 'value'

Object.assign(myObj, { foo });

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you switch around your statements, you could do it:

```
const foo = 'value';
const myObject = { foo };
```

or if you change from `const` to `var` so you can assign a new object to your `myObj`:

```
var myObj = {};
const foo = 'value';
myObj = { foo }
```

Comment: Thanks. I posted myObj = { ...myObj, foo };

Comment: @Lev Thats still the case I think. Did you mean `myObj`'s original values?

Comment: The problem is that in that case I repeat myObj. With destructuring foo and myObj are only indicated once, which is what makes it elegant

Comment: As @OliverCharlesworth said in the comment on your post: 'If you already have things called myObj and foo, you can't avoid referencing them again in order to say "I want to associated myObj with foo"'.